# Bundle data changes abruptly

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-bundle

I have a service and i pass a request object to it.

```
    final Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(context, DataManager.class);
final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("request", request);
        mServiceIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        context.startService(mServiceIntent);
```

The above code is to call my service and have set a bundle in it with an object 'request'. Request object contains an int variable named 'dataVersion'. Now when i get the bundle from the intent :

```
this.request = bundle.getParcelable("request");
```

The dataVersion in the request object changes from 3 to 350 and 350 to -1. It happens very rarely but yes it does happen. Mostly i get the bundle as expected. But when i constantly kill and restart the service in a quick succession, it happens that the dataVersion object changes its value randomly.

Below is my parcelable request :

```
public int updateId;
    public int dataVersion;
    public int priority;
    public boolean setCurrentCompanyOnUpdate;

    public DataUpdateRequest() {
    }

    public DataUpdateRequest(final int dataVersion, final int priority, final boolean setCurrentCompanyOnUpdate) {
        this.updateId = idGen.getAndIncrement();
        this.dataVersion = dataVersion;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.setCurrentCompanyOnUpdate = setCurrentCompanyOnUpdate;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(this.updateId);
        dest.writeInt(this.dataVersion);
        dest.writeInt(this.priority);
        dest.writeByte(this.setCurrentCompanyOnUpdate ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
    }

    protected DataUpdateRequest(Parcel in) {
        this.updateId = in.readInt();
        this.dataVersion = in.readInt();
        this.priority = in.readInt();
        this.setCurrentCompanyOnUpdate = in.readByte() != 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<DataUpdateRequest> CREATOR = new Creator<DataUpdateRequest>() {
        @Override
        public DataUpdateRequest createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new DataUpdateRequest(source);
        }

        @Override
        public DataUpdateRequest[] newArray(int size) {
            return new DataUpdateRequest[size];
        }
    };
```

Comment: nobody knows your `Parcelable` class implementation

Comment: Add your Request object. You have probably an issue with the Parcelable interface implementation. You should read in the exact same order that you've written into the parcel otherwise it doesn't work

Comment: it seems ok, the order and types agree, strange...

Comment: Yeah couldnt find the issue as such. I think constant killing and starting service is doing the job